# Joining Two Tables without PK

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data

TABLE 1

```
TransID | Ref_Entity | Amount
--------+------------+--------
 null   | DEPOSIT    |   0.00
 null   | BANKCHARGES|   0.00
 null   | OTHERS     |   0.00
```

TABLE 2

```
TransID | Ref_Entity | Amount
--------+------------+---------
 1      | DEPOSIT    |   100.00
 1      | BANKCHARGES|   100.00
 2      | OTHERS     |   150.00
```

and would like to have the output like this:

```
 1 | DEPOSIT    |   100.00
 1 | BANKCHARGES|   100.00
 1 | OTHERS     |     0.00
 2 | DEPOSIT    |     0.00
 2 | BANKCHARGES|     0.00
 2 | OTHERS     |   150.00
```

I tried:

```
SELECT 
    * (SELECT '' AS TransID, Ref_Entity, 0.00 AS Amount 
       FROM TABLE1
       UNION
       SELECT TransID, Ref_Entity, Amount 
       FROM TABLE2
      )
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That last row `1 | OTHERS | 150.00` should be `2 | OTHERS | 150.00` Right?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic, right. I laready modified it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the distinct combination of `TransID` and `Ref_Entity` then do a `LEFT JOIN` on `Table2`

```
WITH Combinations(TransID, Ref_Entity) AS(
    SELECT 
        t2.TransID, t1.Ref_Entity
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT Ref_Entity FROM Table1) t1
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT TransID FROM Table2) t2
)
SELECT
    c.TransID,
    c.Ref_Entity,
    Amount = ISNULL(t2.Amount, 0)
FROM Combinations c
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON c.TransID = t2.TransID
    AND c.Ref_Entity = t2.Ref_Entity;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/696969)</kbd>

Comment: It works but is it suitable if tables do not have same number of columns.? I try adding more columns/field names (for Table2), and it says that the column name is invalid.

Comment: sorry. I should add other fields in the "Select distinct" query.

Comment: @angel Sorry, I added `DISTINCT` in the Cte.

Comment: In the first CTE - if you are doing DISTINCT  t2.TransID, t1.Ref_Entity there is no need to use two more DISTINCT's in subqueries. `SELECT DISTINCT t2.TransID, t1.Ref_Entity
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2` will get same result with less workload

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I forgot I already added the `DISTINCT` clause in the subqueries. Thanks for pointing that out.